# How to check if an object has changed property in deserialisation c#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am using `JsonConvert` to get data from my api every 15 seconds.

This data is going to an observable collection which is of type [here](https://gist.github.com/itajaja/7507120).

I can't make use of the `TrulyObservableCollection` because every 15 second I am assigning the api to the collection as follows:

```
collection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ManifestJSON>(uri)
```

Is there a way to check if an existing object in the DeserializeObject has change so I can modify my collection?

So I can use `.Add` and `.Remove` instead of overriding the collection.

Comment: Probably only by deserialising to a *new* object and comparing them.

Comment: Iterate through the collections and compare the objects?

Comment: Yeap, do it all the time.  There are different ways to achieve it, Helper class, DAL manager, or use custom comparators and a quick linq to update or modify existing.  If the items have unique identifiers then hopefully you're using those and problem solved already but if not boil up a little logic to update existing.  I agree changing entire collection is not good.  Update the existing is better.

Comment: Ok did what @mm8 said and it works(If you post an answer I will accept) . Does iterating needs to be async or it will process fast enough?

Comment: @user8088399: If you don't have a lot of elements to iterate over, you might as well execute the iteration on the UI thread. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate through the collections and compare the objects.

If you find a match, you update the corresponding object and if you don't you either add or remove it from the data-bound source collection.

You could perform the actual iterating on a background thread in order to keep the app responsive, but you will still need to add/remove items from the source collection back on the UI thread so doing this is probably pretty pointless from a performance perspective anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your JSON format (obviously if your message includes the date then this won't work); but one possibility might be to compare the raw JSON before you deserialise it.  It's certainly not foolproof, but if you're reading the stream from the same source, you might be okay with a string comparison.